# How do I create a dynamic object in Blazor WebAssembly?

Tags: blazor-webassembly

The code below is one of the Blazor WebAssembly example.

```
@code {

protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    string _baseURL = "";

    int caseSwitch = new Random().Next(1, 4);
    switch (caseSwitch)
    {
        case 1:
            _baseURL = "https://randomuser.me/api/";
            break;
        case 2:
            _baseURL = "https://reqres.in/api/users?page=2";
            break;
        default:
            _baseURL = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos";
            break;
    }
    dynamic? items = await Http.GetFromJsonAsync<dynamic>(_baseURL);
}
```

}

and when I did a breakpoint on the items variable, it is null. How do I create a dynamic object so that when any of the Rest API is called, it can fit into the object dynamically without me needing to create 3 different classes with it own different properties? Thanks